# ImageButton background color with appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I've got problems to have a good background from an AppCompatImageButton, just to try I'm comparing this two layouts:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonI"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/icolor"
        android:tint="@color/accent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/magnify"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/scolor"
        android:tint="@color/accent"
        android:src="@drawable/magnify"/>
```

and the style file:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
</style>
```

As you can see from this image however, the background of ImageButton is "normal" while there isn't any background in the appcompat one. How can I have the "normal" background using `AppCompatImageButton`?

[image: Current layout rendering]

Answer (score 2):

A good way to style the Button is to use the style `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored`.

The `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` style extends the `Widget.AppCompat.Button` style and applies automatically the accent color you selected in your app theme.

```
<Button
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
 />
```

To customize the background color without changing the accent color in your main theme you can create a custom theme for your Button using the `android:theme` attribute and extending the `ThemeOverlay` theme.

```
 <Button  
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"  
     android:theme="@style/MyButtonTheme"/>
```

defining the following theme:

```
 <!-- res/values/themes.xml -->
  <style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"> 
      <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_color</item> 
 </style>
```

Comment: @greywolf82 I've finally realize what was the reason! You have to extend your activity from AppCompatActivity.

Comment: background is white on pre 21. Can you please tell how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of support library are you using, but before there was bug in the library which is reported here,

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78428

But they have resolved it in the latest update,

> Yes, it appears to work now with the introduction of
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton in AppCompat v22.1.0, color
>   can be controlled at overall theme level with "colorButtonNormal".
>
> http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html
>   http://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/

for theme

```
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>
```

for version 21

```
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks

Comment: try using above in your theme